# Creating IntentService, not called onHandleIntent()

Tags: android, service, intentservice

Why my onHandleIntent now called?
So, if i extend class by Service it's working normally. I need intentService because this has non-main thread feature method.

My manifest file:

```
<service
        android:name=".tools.NewsService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false">
    </service>
```

Service called by `startService(..);`

```
public class NewsService extends IntentService {

private NotificationManager notificationManager;
final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
public static final int timeout = 86400000;  // 24 hours
private Timer mTimer = null;
String urlNews = AppParams.newsUrl;

public NewsService() {
    super("name");
}

public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onCreate");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onHandleIntent");
    if (mTimer != null)
        mTimer.cancel();
    else
        mTimer = new Timer();   //recreate new
    mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimeDisplay(), 0, 10*1000);
}

@Override
public void onStart(@Nullable Intent intent, int startId) {
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onStart");
}

public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mTimer.cancel();
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onDestroy");
}
```

Comment: Is `onCreate()` called?

Comment: You need something *other* than `IntentService`. An `IntentService` is destroyed as soon as `onHandleIntent()` returns. You specifically do *not* want that to happen. You need your service to be running as long as you want your `Timer` to be executing.

Comment: @Onik, no, isnt called.

Comment: @CommonsWare, can you recommend any for execute asynctask always after 24 hours in background?

Comment: For periodic background work, try to use `JobScheduler` (or, eventually, `WorkManager`).

Comment: @CommonsWare, ok, try it today, thank you